# Pig Load with Schema giving error

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

I have a file called data_tuple_bag.txt on hdfs with the following content:

```
10,{(1,2),(2,3)}
11,{(4,5),(6,7)}
```

I am creating a relation as below :

```
D = LOAD '/user/pig_demo/data_tuple_bag.txt' AS (f1:int,B:{T:(t1:int,t2:int)});
```

When I DUMP it it is giving me ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 2 time(s) as well as FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 2 time(s) and an empty output.

I changed the relation to :

```
D = LOAD '/user/pig_demo/data_tuple_bag.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,B:{T:(t1:int,t2:int)});
```

Now it's only giving FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 2 time(s) and output as :

```
(10,)
(11,)
```

I have another file data_only_bag.txt with following in it:

```
{(1,2),(2,3)}
{(4,5),(6,7)}
```

The relation is defined as :

```
A = LOAD '/user/pig_demo/data_only_bag.txt' AS (B:{T:(t1:int,t2:int)});
```

And it works.

Now I am updating the data_only_bag.txt as below:

```
10,{(1,2),(2,3)}
11,{(4,5),(6,7)}
```

And the relation is :

```
A = LOAD '/user/pig_demo/data_only_bag.txt' AS (f1:int,B:{T:(t1:int,t2:int)});
```

I am getting : 
(,)
(,)
When I DUMP it it is giving me ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 2 time(s) as well as FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 2 time(s) and an empty output.

Now I am updating the relation to :

```
A = LOAD '/user/pig_demo/data_only_bag.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,B:{T:(t1:int,t2:int)});
```

Now it's only giving FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 2 time(s) and output as :

```
(10,)
(11,)
```

Same as before.

Can anybody tell me what wrong am I doing here?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It failed to parse the input with the provided schema,
Try with this :

```
D = LOAD '/user/pig_demo/data_tuple_bag.txt' USING PigStorage(',') 
AS (f1:int, B: {T1: (t1:int, t2:int),T2: (t1:int, t2:int)});
```

Comment: @AbhilashDK, That exactly the difinition of a Bag in Piglatin. Does it works ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. But a bag can be a collection of tuples right. When i write B:{T:(t1:int,t2:int)} and just have data like (1,2),(2,3)
(4,5),(6,7) it works. But only when I introduce another field in the first f1 i am getting the above error.

Comment: Please update your question, and add a typical input file for each case